# Values of $z$ for which $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos(nz)}{2^n}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to find the values of $z\in \mathbb{C}$ for which the following series is convergent:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos(nz)}{2^n}$$
So far I know that if $z\in \mathbb{R}$, then the series converges. If $z=iy$, $y\in \mathbb{R}$ then
$$\frac{\cos(nyi)}{2^n}=\frac{e^{-yn}+e^{yn}}{2^{n+1}}$$
and when $n\longrightarrow\infty$, this diverges if $y>\ln(2)$. Then the series can't converge for those values of $z$. However I don't know what else to do. Can someone help me?

Comment: Since $\Big|2^{-n}e^{izn}\Big|^{1/n}\leq e^{|z|}/2$, convergence holds for all $z$ with $|z|\leq \log(2)$. If $z\in\mathbb{R}$, then $|\cos(nz)|\leq1$ and so convergence is everywhere on the real line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing $\cos nz  =\frac{e^{inz}+e^{-inz}}{2}$ it will converge if both:

$$\sum_{n} \left(\frac{e^{iz}}2\right)^n$$
and
$$\sum_{n} \left(\frac{e^{-iz}}2\right)^n$$
converge. One of these always converges (why?,) so the original sum converges if and only if these both converge.

These converge if and only if $\left|e^{iz}\right|<2$ and $\left|e^{-iz}\right|<2.$

This happens when $$\left|\operatorname{Im}(z)\right|<\ln 2$$

Comment: (+1) Nice. It's a pity that I made a mistake in my answer (which I deleted).

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Since $\Big|2^{-n}e^{\pm izn}\Big|^{1/n}\leq e^{|z|}/2$, convergence holds for all $z$ with $|z|\leq \log(2)$

More generally, if $z=a+ib$ then $\Big|2^{-n}e^{\pm izn}\Big|^{1/n}=2^{-1}e^{\pm b}$ and convergence follows for $|b|\leq \log(2)$.

This contains in particular the case where $z\in\mathbb{R}$.